# Sid have empty values ​after SharePoint UserProfile Sync

Tags: 2013, active-directory, profile-sync, active-directory-import

I use SharePoint Server 2013 and I am trying  user profile synchronization from Active Directory. I followed https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/meacoex/2013/08/04/step-by-step-active-directory-import-for-sharepoint-2013/ .

I can see all Active Directory users in Sharepoint. I request GetUserInfo and GetGroupCollectionFromUser in Sharepoint API via soapUI but sid field is empty for all user. You can see the response as follow:

```
<GetUserInfo>
   <User ID="17" Sid="" Name="testUser" LoginName="i:0#.w|lagom\testUser" Email="testUser@tesDomain.com" Notes="" IsSiteAdmin="False" IsDomainGroup="False" Flags="0"/>
</GetUserInfo>
```

I follow [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms772554%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and saw the sid value isn't empty.

How can I sync "Sid" ?

How can I fill the sid field?

How can I configure Sharepoint or Active Directory?

Answer (score 2):

Try with the REST api, like this:

```
<siteurl>/_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/getuserprofilepropertyfor(accountname=@v, propertyname='SID')?@v='<accountname>'
```

Comment: Thanks, I could see "sid" value via your method.  Why can not I see via my method?

Comment: The SPUser.Sid property seems to not be populated when you use Claims. You should use the SystemUserKey, like this: _spPageContextInfo.SystemUserKey , which returns the value with the format 1:0).w|<sid>, or call the REST api for other users than the current one.

Comment: You could also use JSOM code: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj920104%28v=office.15%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Is it usual not to be populated of sids at Claims or does it point a misconfiguration at AD synch?

Comment: Is the expected behaviour, not a misconfiguration of the User Profile Sync

Comment: Thanks for your information. But My app use "UserGroup.GetUserInfo Method" and "UserGroup.GetUserCollectionFromGroup Method" in SP web service. I looked at this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms772554%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 and saw the sid value isn't empty. So, I should fix empty sid problem instead of alternate solution. How can I fill the sid field? How can I configure Sharepoint or Active Directory?

Comment: That documentation refers to Windows SharePoint Services 3, not SharePoint Server 2013. OOTB does not import SID when using Claims, so you cannot configure SharePoint or AD.  In order to help you, add to your question the code you are using for making the call to the web service. There is maybe an alternate solution, like the property "systemUserKey" of the variabile "_spPageContextInfo" (_spPageContextInfo.systemUserKey) which value has the following format: 1:0).w|<sid>

Comment: Sorry, I shared wrong reference. For 2013: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcusergroup.usergroup.getusercollectionfromgroup(v=office.15).aspx